# Python 3.5.1 if else: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

```
number = [1,3,5]

position = 0

while 
position < len(number):

    numbers = number[position]

    if numbers % 2==0:
        print('found even number',numbers)
        break
    position = position +1
    else:
```

I got SyntaxError: invalid syntax, after i push enter after else:

Help me please

Answer (score 2):

The indentation of your position = position + 1 statement is wrong.

It is at the same level as your if and else statements, so separates them.

Indent or move it and you'll be fine.

Also, you could simplify the code a bit by changing the while loop to a for loop as:

```
number = [1, 3, 5]

for num in number:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Found even number", num)
    else:
```

Hard to say exactly given the short snippet of code, but it looks like the while loop is unnecessary given what is there

Comment: position < len(number) has to be same level as if and else?

Comment: No, it's part of the while statement. That could all be on one line as "while position < len(number):" then the rest. You need to move the other position statement outside the if-else blocks.